# Meaning of "so to speak"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can you give me a **simple** definition for this without using: as it were, .....

I'm having problem finding an equivalent.

> In that relationship it's very much Lorna who wears the trousers, so to speak.

> We have to pull down the barriers, so to speak, of poverty.

Comment: You could use '***[as a matter of fact](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-a-matter-of-fact)***' for the first sentence.

Comment: @VarunKN It wouldn't mean the same thing. "So to speak" highlights the fact that it is a metaphor.

Comment: Wear the trousers is an idiom for someone in control (usually of a household). Long ago, women didnt wear trousers, only dresses. Men used to be exclusively in control, and so were refered to as "wearing the trousers/pants". So to speak is used to say a previous statement might have been improperly, exaggeratedly or metaphorically worded.

Comment: Since the sentences explain two idioms, you can use "figuratively speaking ".

Answer (score 2):

The term *so to speak* indicates that you are speaking metaphorically. In casual spoken English, it is equivalent to indicating quotation marks using hand gestures. An equivalent phrase (and direct replacement) is *in a manner of speaking*:

> In that relationship it's very much Lorna who wears the trousers, in a manner of speaking.

An older phrase (in written English) is *let the reader understand*:

> So when you see standing in the holy place 'the abomination that causes desolation,' spoken of through the prophet Daniel -- **let the reader understand** -- then let those who are in Judea flee to the mountains.

Matthew 24:15-16 (NIV)

Comment: Your first example is good, but I have to disagree with your second. I don't think Jesus was saying that his reference to Daniel was a metaphor, but rather that the reference to Daniel might literally be difficult to understand.

Comment: What @Jay said. Other versions of the Bible render *let the reader understand* as *Reader, **pay attention!**, he who reads should consider, let him that readeth understand, etc.* It really does just mean ***take careful note because this is important***, not ***this is a metaphor***.

Answer (score 0):

[*So to speak*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so-to-speak) is usually used when the speaker wants to emphasize something as a matter of a fact or to say something in a straightforward way, or just remarking that what's been said before is just one way of explaining it. Put in simple terms, you're speaking metaphorically.

For example, speaker B, instead of saying:

- A: What do you do for a living?
- B: I write peculiar science fiction books, looking for all the required material in scientific papers and libraries, in order to describe everything in a very detailed way,

he/she could say:

- A: What do you do for a living?
- B: I'm writer, so to speak.

Probably there're better examples to better explain it to you, but at the moment I had only this in mind.